# how to kill running script within a dead screen session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a script started in a screen session, then detached, tried to reattach but now this session is dead.
The script is still running.
How I can kill the script, being unable to reattach the screen session?
Unfortunatly I have killed the screen process shown with `ps`.

Is there any possibility to stop the script?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in a linux enviroment, as you say you used ps. If you have the uuid of the process, you can kill it by using `kill < uuid> -9`. If you know the process by name, try `pkill < name>`. Both cases should work on a terminal. If you are unable to open a terminal, try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>. You should see a login prompt, followed by a terminal. To get back to the xsession do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>

If everything else fails, try killing all processes: `kill -9 -1`. This should get you back to your display manager.

If you killed your screen process, try `xinit` from a terminal and then try to go back.

If you can't see the process, try `ps aux`

Comment: might need a `ps` first to determine uuid, followed by a `kill uuid -9`

Comment: Thanks to your answer. But the problem is I cant see the script as a process with ps, there is only a "bash", "sshd" and the "ps" itself.

Comment: I tried ps aux | grep myuserID but no process linked to my script or any screen session.